# How to use third party javascript controls in outsystem?

Tags: forge, outsystems

I want to integerate third party javascript/jquery controls in Outssystem. But i can't find any details.

Answer (score 0):

You got multiple options to execute Javascript in Outsystems.

**JavaScript option of the e-space.**

When you select the current e-spece you will see a "JavaScript" option under the Web header. This will be available for all screen/web blocks in the e-space.

**Javascript option in a web block/screen**

When you select a screen or web block you will see a "JavaScript" option under the advanced header.

**RunJavaScript server action**

You can use this server action from the HTTPRequestHandler module to run javascript using a server action.

**Expression**

You can use an expression to run Javascript by wrapping it into `<script>...</script>` tags. You will need to set the "Escape Content" option of the expression to false.

Note: With this method you can use variables in your script. To avoid script injection you will need to escape those with the `EncodeJavascript()` function.

Comment: Where could i add the html element and how to bind event for those elements?

Comment: @MuthukrishnanKandasamy I'm not sure if I understand you. Do you want to bind a javascript event handler to an Outsystems element?

Comment: Hi @Mark Baijens, My exact requirement is to to render the third party controls in outsystems. So that, i need create html elements and need to refer the some cdn links.

Comment: @MuthukrishnanKandasamy I think it will be best to not use cdn because the will make your website depended on the cdn swebite. If cdn is down then you will have problems on your website too, if the get hacked then you even have a security issue on your site. Therefore i recommend to put the source code of the third party controls in a web block.